# Send e-mail upon user login for MySQL

Tags: mysql, email

I know that I can use [ONESEC](http://www.ossec.net/) to e-mail myself if someone logs into my server but I was wondering if I could do the same thing if someone logs into a specific user for MySQL. My GoogleFu seems to be failing on this one.

Comment: You can easily set up triggers in MySQL to update a logon history table http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-and-logoff-trigger-for-auditing and possibly even use the OSSec [database](http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/output/database-output.html) itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup MySQL to log to syslog and configure nowadzys versatiles syslog daemon (eg rsyslogd) to trigger an email when it matcha mysql log message that matches the appropriate pattern.